# Horizontal divs with alignment

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to get away from using the table layout to do specific layouts. I know it's sloppy programming so I'm redoing it. I can't seem to recreate something like this using the div tag:

```
<table border=10 cellpadding=10 width="90%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="143">
            <img src="http://blah.com/images/133widepixelimage.jpg">
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            Some text describing the image
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've got the border, padding, width and alignment all done in a CSS file, and that works fine. But setting the width of the centered image still doesn't allow the centered text to show up to the right of the image. It still wraps to the next line. If I center the image left, and set `float: left`, that works.  But not two centered even if the parent div is wide enough to accommodate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```css
.container{
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    border: 10px solid black;
    height: 50px;
    border-left-color: gray;
    border-top-color: gray;
}
.img{
    width: 143px;
}
.img > img{
    width: 100%;
}
.container > div {
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
.text{
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="img">
            <img src="http://blah.com/images/133widepixelimage.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            Some text describing the image
        </div>
 </div>
```

You can do it with divs, using flexbox like the example showed above

Comment: Ok. I can see how that would work. But let's throw a little more complexity into it. How about a 2x2 grid, without borders of any kind (except the container border) with different sized images in the left two rows, and topleft text being centered while the bottomleft text is left aligned. And for extra credit, set the left rows width to be 20 greater than the width of the widest image.

Comment: oops ... make that topleft=topright and bottomleft=bottomright for the text locations.

Comment: @user2021539 this is not the OP question. I just show you what you asked in the first place.